# Simplify $(7-2i)(7+2i)$. Found difference between mine and solution guide's and didn't know why.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I looked up the solution guide and found out:
$(7-2i)(7+2i)$
$=49-(2i)^2$
$=49+4$
$=53$

Why the unknown "$i$" just disappeared$?$ I supposed it might be:
$(7-2i)(7+2i)$
$=49-(2i)^2$
$=49-4i$
does it?

May someone tell me which one is right and tell me the reasons? Thank you so much.

Comment: $i$ is not "the unknown" there, it is the imaginary unit, so $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: I would assume that $i$ is the imaginary unit, not a variable, and then, by definition, $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of $i$ as a variable when what is meant is $i=\sqrt{-1}$ so that when you FOIL out you get $i^2=-1$.

Comment: @Finn Even if you treat $i$ as indeterminate, it should be $49 - 4i^2$, not $49-4i$.  Then the fact that $i^2 = -1$ fully reconciles the two solutions.

Answer (score 6):

We have $(7-2i)(7+2i)=49+14i-14i-4i^2=49-4i^2.$  Note that $i=\sqrt{-1}\implies i^2=(\sqrt{-1})^2=-1.$  Therefore,
$$(7-2i)(7+2i)=49-4i^2=49-4(-1)=49+4=53$$

Comment: Your explanation is very clear. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

What you did wrong is that $(2i)^2$ is not $4i$, but rather $4i^2$, which is equivalent to $-4$.

Comment: ...I left it out. Thank you.

Comment: @Finn no problem. I'm not sure why my answer was downvoted, as it answers your question. :(